# Can an artificial intelligence eventually think like a human?

Tags: philosophy, human-like

It seems to me that the way neural networks are trained is similar to the way we educate a child (or a person, in general).

Can an AI *eventually* think like a human?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fully understand the human mind before you can say that a  machine can eventually think like a human. However, the human brain is nowhere near fully understood, nor is human cognition.